# Back key behavior after up action

Tags: android

Here http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html is some tips about **back** and **up** navigation. It's quite clear what does **up** do on [this example](http://developer.android.com/design/media/navigation_between_siblings_market1.png), it closes those activities.

But what happen [here](http://developer.android.com/design/media/navigation_between_siblings_market2.png)? I go to the market, open book, then another one, then open movie, and then I decide to press **up** to go to movies category.
What has happened to books activities?
Can I somehow go to them?
Where do I go when I click back button, to the market?

Answer (score 1):

The UP button will navigate within App. The UP button ensures that the user remains within App. The topmost screen of an app should not present the UP Button.

However, the system BACK button can return the user to the Home screen, or even to a different app, which is unlike UP Button.
When the previously viewed screen is also the hierarchical parent of the current screen, pressing the Back button has the same result as pressing an Up button

Comment: Sure, but you didn't answer my question :) Where do I go in my example after back pressed and why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is book activities, I think it is fragments. But about your question.
If you read the navigation details it states:

> The system Back button is used to navigate, in reverse chronological
>   order, through the history of screens the user has recently worked
>   with. It is generally based on the temporal relationships between
>   screens, rather than the app's hierarchy.

In other words you should go back to selected movie, from there the selected book and etc. This however needs to be implemented by the developer and often it isn't. Which is why back button might just bring you back to market/play store from the movies top category.

**Edit**: So above was my first thought. Based on experimenting with google apps and looking into the example I change my advice to following:

When you go up to the new root (movie) then the app should close. The reason for this is simply that the user has navigated to a new top hierachy and would probarbly be anoyed by having to go through whole the last navigation. This also means that when the user clicks up in movies whole the back track stack is lost.

Comment: So you think that even in first example I shouldn't close those activities (let's stay that they are activities) and back navigate to them? That would be quite unexpected.

Comment: Well it states: "in reverse chronological order, through the history of screens the user has recently worked with." This could also be interpreted as from movie top element to book top element... but as a user I'd expect it to go back to last view. Just like in a web browser (where you get frustrated if there is a lot of redirections).

Comment: Yes, but it's not a browser :) Even Android Market is closing those activities. So my question is still open, because we shouldn't sometimes close activities and some times browse through history.

Comment: But I'm telling you Android market is not activities, its most likely fragments.

Comment: That cleaning up of the fragments happens automatically. Well it probably does so as well for activities. But in short, just store the path the user has taken, then it should be pretty straight forward to back track as well. Any crucial information should be stored persistent anyway.

Comment: @Mikooos I've changed my opinion based on experimenting and useability.